# How can I create a pausableBuffer w/ rxjs 5

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to make what I think is a [pausable buffer](https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/632607554263117828)

I had someone share their code for this, but I cannot figure out how to turn it into a custom operation (without typescript / just ES6.

```
const attach = Rx.Observable.timer(0 * 1000, 8 * 1000).mapTo('@');
const detach = Rx.Observable.timer(4 * 1000, 8 * 1000).mapTo('#');

const input = Rx.Observable.interval(1* 1000);
const pauser = attach.mapTo(true).merge(detach.mapTo(false));

input
  .publish(_input => _input
    .combineLatest(pauser, (v, b) => b)
    .filter(e => e)
    .publish(_switch => _input.bufferWhen(() => _switch.take(1)))
  )
  .flatMap(e => Rx.Observable.from(e))
  .concatMap(e => Rx.Observable.empty().delay(150).startWith(e))
```

Can someone help me create that so that I can just do `input.pausableBuffer(pauser)` (and maybe define a startsWith).

Comment: See this similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747633/pausable-rxjs-stream/57796073#57796073

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to the prototype like this:

```
var pausableBuffer = function(pauser) {
  return this.publish(_input => _input
    .combineLatest(pauser, (v, b) => b)
    .filter(e => e)
    .publish(_switch => _input.bufferWhen(() => _switch.take(1)))
  )
  .flatMap(e => Rx.Observable.from(e));
}

Rx.Observable.prototype.pausableBuffer = pausableBuffer;
```

One thing to remember is that this will start in the paused state. To start it in the active state instead, add `.startWith(true)` to `pauser`.

```
var pausableBuffer = function(pauser) {
  return this.publish(_input => _input
    .combineLatest(pauser.startWith(true), (v, b) => b)
    .filter(e => e)
    .publish(_switch => _input.bufferWhen(() => _switch.take(1)))
  )
  .flatMap(e => Rx.Observable.from(e));
}

Rx.Observable.prototype.pausableBuffer = pausableBuffer;
```

Update 2019: RxJs 6 style:

```
var pausableBuffer = function(pauser) {
  return (source) => source.pipe(publish(_input => 
  combineLatest(_input, pauser.pipe(startWith(true))).pipe(
    map(([inp, pa]) => pa),
    filter(pa => pa),
    publish(_switch => _input.pipe(bufferWhen(() => _switch.pipe(take(1)))))
  )),
    mergeMap(e => from(e))
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/vuhuyuwoce/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: What does this example look like in RxJS 6?

Comment: @chrismarx Simpler actually, you add pipe and instead of adding the function to the prototype you make it an inner function that returns a function. The paramer of the inner function will replace what right now is `this` in the example. `pausableBuffer = (pauser) => (source) => source.publish(_input => _input.pipe(...))`

Comment: Thanks for including an example. I ran into problems using this answer since this.publish isn't valid anymore, and just switching to "publish" didn't work either. I ended up using the Buffering example from here, which uses bufferToggle and windowToggle - https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd

Comment: @chrismarx [`publish`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/publish) is still a valid operator. I do just realize i forgot to  `pipe` it.

Comment: @chrismarx I added the full RxJs 6 soluion + JsBin demo to the answer.