# Pause RxJS stream based on a value in the stream

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a simple component with a single button that starts and pauses a stream of numbers generated by RxJS timer.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, timer, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, bufferToggle, windowToggle, mergeMap, mergeAll, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button (click)="toggle()">{{ (active$ | async) ? 'Pause' : 'Play' }}</button>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  active$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const on$ = this.active$.pipe(filter(v => v));
    const off$ = this.active$.pipe(filter(v => !v));

    const stream$ = timer(500, 500).pipe(share());

    const out$ = merge(
      stream$.pipe(
        bufferToggle(off$, () => on$),
        mergeAll(),
      ),
      stream$.pipe(
        windowToggle(on$, () => off$),
        mergeAll(),
      ),
    );

    out$.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }

  toggle(): void {
    this.active$.next(!this.active$.value);
  }
}
```

[image]

This works perfectly but I need to add one more feature!

**I need to pause the stream automatically based on a value in the stream satisfying a condition.**

For example, pause the stream if the latest value is a multiple of 5.

---

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Here is a runnable example on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hjznn

Comment: So what should be the expected output?

Comment: The sequence should be the same. The stream should be paused not only by clicking on the button bat also by receiving certain values in the stream.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible to either (1) expand your current bufferToggle / windowToggle approach or to (2) use a custom buffer implementation.

## 1. Expanding the bufferToggle / windowToggle approach

You can add an array to the operator queue after `bufferToggle`.

1. When `bufferToggle` emits append those values to the array.
2. Take values from the array until a certain element in the array matches a halt condition.
3. Emit those values and pause your stream.

#### pausable ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vq7xsh))

The `pausable` operator will emit values that match the halt condition and then stop the stream immediately.

```
export function pausable<T, O>(
  on$: Observable<any>, // when on$ emits 'pausable' will emit values from the buffer and all incoming values 
  off$: Observable<O>, // when off$ emits 'pausable' will stop emitting and buffer incoming values
  haltCondition: (value: T) => boolean, // if 'haltCondition' returns true for a value in the stream the stream will be paused
  pause: () => void, // pauses the stream by triggering the given on$ and off$ observables
  spread: boolean = true // if true values from the buffer will be emitted separately, if 'false' values from the buffer will be emitted in an array
) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => defer(() => { // defer is used so that each subscription gets its own buffer
    let buffer: T[] = [];
    return merge(
      source.pipe(
        bufferToggle(off$, () => on$),
        tap(values => buffer = buffer.concat(values)), // append values to your custom buffer
        map(_ => buffer.findIndex(haltCondition)), // find the index of the first element that matches the halt condition
        tap(haltIndex => haltIndex >= 0 ? pause() : null), // pause the stream when a value matching the halt condition was found
        map(haltIndex => buffer.splice(0, haltIndex === -1 ? customBuffer.length : haltIndex + 1)), // get all values from your custom buffer until a haltCondition is met
        mergeMap(toEmit => spread ? from(toEmit) : toEmit.length > 0 ? of(toEmit) : EMPTY) // optional value spread (what your mergeAll did)
      ),
      source.pipe(
        windowToggle(on$, () => off$),
        mergeMap(x => x),
        tap(value => haltCondition(value) ? pause() : null), // pause the stream when an unbuffered value matches the halt condition
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

You can adjust this operator to your specific needs e.g. use less input parameters and incorporate `share` into it, see [this version with less parameters](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggof15).

**Usage**

```
active$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
on$ = this.active$.pipe(filter(v => v));
off$ = this.active$.pipe(filter(v => !v));

interval(500).pipe(
  share(),
  pausable(on$, off$, v => this.active$.value && this.pauseOn(v), () => this.active$.next(false))
).subscribe(console.log);

pauseOn = (value: number) => value > 0 && value % 10 === 0
```

---

## 2. A fully custom buffer

You can go with a fully custom approach using only one input observable similar to [Brandon's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56840175/9423231).

#### bufferIf ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxzkv5))

`bufferIf` will buffer incoming values when the given `condition` emits `true` and emits all values from the buffer or passes new ones through when the `condition` is `false`.

```
export function bufferIf<T>(condition: Observable<boolean>) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => defer(() => {
    const buffer: T[] = [];
    let paused = false;
    let sourceTerminated = false;
    return merge( // add a custon streamId to values from the source and the condition so that they can be differentiated later on
      source.pipe(map(v => [v, 0]), finalize(() => sourceTerminated = true)),
      condition.pipe(map(v => [v, 1]))
    ).pipe( // add values from the source to the buffer or set the paused variable
      tap(([value, streamId]) => streamId === 0 ? buffer.push(value as T) : paused = value as boolean), 
      switchMap(_ => new Observable<T>(s => {
        setTimeout(() => { // map to a stream of values taken from the buffer, setTimeout is used so that a subscriber to the condition outside of this function gets the values in the correct order (also see Brandons answer & comments)
          while (buffer.length > 0 && !paused) s.next(buffer.shift())
        }, 0)
      })), // complete the stream when the source terminated and the buffer is empty
      takeWhile(_ => !sourceTerminated || buffer.length > 0, true) 
    );
  })
}
```

**Usage**

```
pause$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

interval(500).pipe(
  bufferIf(this.pause$),
  tap(value => this.pauseOn(value) ? this.pause$.next(true) : null)
).subscribe(console.log);

pauseOn = (value: number) => value > 0 && value % 10 === 0
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a custom pause operator that will just accumulate values in a buffer when the pause signal is `true`, and emit them one by one when it is `false`.

Combine it with a simple `tap` operator to toggle the behavior subject pause signal when the value hits a specific condition, and you have something will pause on button click and also pause when the value meets a condition (multiple of 12 in this case):

Here is the `pause` operator:

```
function pause<T>(pauseSignal: Observable<boolean>) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => Observable.create(observer => {
    const buffer = [];
    let paused = false;
    let error;
    let isComplete = false;

    function notify() {
      while (!paused && buffer.length) {
        const value = buffer.shift();
        observer.next(value);
      }

      if (!buffer.length && error) {
        observer.error(error);
      }

      if (!buffer.length && isComplete) {
        observer.complete();
      }
    }

    const subscription = pauseSignal.subscribe(
      p => {
        paused = !p;
        setTimeout(notify, 0);
      },
      e => {
        error = e;
        setTimeout(notify, 0);
      },
      () => {});

    subscription.add(source.subscribe(
      v => {
        buffer.push(v);
        notify();
      },
      e => {
        error = e;
        notify();
      },
      () => {
        isComplete = true;
        notify();
      }
    ));

    return subscription;
  });
}
```

Here is the usage of it:

```
const CONDITION = x => (x > 0) && ((x % 12) === 0); // is multiple
this.active$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
const stream$ = timer(500, 500);
const out$ = stream$.pipe(
  pause(this.active$),
  tap(value => {
    if (CONDITION(value)) {
      this.active$.next(false);
    }
  }));

this.d = out$.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

And a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvxnbf

Comment: There is a slight bug. If after a pause I wait for about 10 seconds and then press "Play" it emits next 12 items and stops (this is OK), but the button text is "Pause" (should be "Play")

Comment: thanks.  So there's a "feature" of the BehaviorSubject that if you recursively set values, then the observers receive the values out of order.  I think I fixed the issue by using `setTimeout` around the calls to `notify` when the pause signal fires.  There's probably a way to use `observeOn` and schedulers to fix this, but *shrug*

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to do it. Use the `timer()` just as an emitter, and increment a count separately. This gives you a little more direct control.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  active = true;
  out$: Observable<number>;

  count = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const stream$ = timer(500, 500);

    this.out$ = stream$.pipe(
      filter(v => this.active),
      map(v => {
        this.count += 1;
        return this.count;
      }),
      tap(v => {
        if (this.count % 5 === 0) {
          this.active = false;
        }
      })
    )
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzs7zh

Comment: This misses the part with buffer. We don't have to stop the emission of values. We have to keep them in a buffer and pause printing.

Comment: @TarasHupalo Using a buffer is just a different way of doing it. What are you getting from using the buffer that you don't get from doing it this way?

Comment: This approach filters the stream. I don't want to lose values. The emitter can be something else then `timer()`

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the desired behaviour is not related to getting the values that the timer emits per se, and that instead of pausing notifications to an ongoing stream (in your example, the timer continues even if we don't see the values being printed), it's okay to actually stop emitting when paused.

My solution is inspired by the [Stopwatch recipe](https://www.learnrxjs.io/recipes/stop-watch.html)

The solution below uses two separate buttons for play and pause, but you can adjust this to taste. We pass the (ViewChild) buttons to the service in the ngAfterViewInit hook of the component, then we subscribe to the stream.

```
// pausable.component.ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.pausableService.initPausableStream(this.start.nativeElement, this.pause.nativeElement);

    this.pausableService.counter$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)) // don't forget to unsubscribe :)
      .subscribe((state: State) => {
        console.log(state.value); // whatever you need
    });
  }
```

```
// pausable.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { merge, fromEvent, Subject, interval, NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo, startWith, scan, switchMap, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface State {
  active: boolean;
  value: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PausableService {

  public counter$;

  constructor() { }

  initPausableStream(start: HTMLElement, pause: HTMLElement) {

    // convenience functions to map an element click to a result
    const fromClick = (el: HTMLElement) => fromEvent(el, 'click');
    const clickMapTo = (el: HTMLElement, obj: {}) => fromClick(el).pipe(mapTo(obj));

    const pauseByCondition$ = new Subject();
    const pauseCondition = (state: State): boolean => state.value % 5 === 0 && state.value !== 0;

    // define the events that may trigger a change
    const events$ = merge(
      clickMapTo(start, { active: true }),
      clickMapTo(pause, { active: false }),
      pauseByCondition$.pipe(mapTo({ active: false }))
    );

    // switch the counter stream based on events
    this.counter$ = events$.pipe(
      startWith({ active: true, value: 0 }),
      scan((state: State, curr) => ({ ...state, ...curr }), {}),
      switchMap((state: State) => state.active
        ? interval(500).pipe(
          tap(_ => ++state.value),
          map(_ => state))
        : NEVER),
      tap((state: State) => {
        if (pauseCondition(state)) {
          pauseByCondition$.next(); // trigger pause
        }
      })
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple as it can get with one `windowToggle` and use active.next(false) 
working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdw7kw

```
 defer(() => {
      let count = 0;
      return stream$.pipe(
        windowToggle(on$, () => off$),
        exhaustMap(obs => obs),
        mergeMap(_ => {
          if ((++count) % 5 === 0) {
            this.active$.next(false)
            return never()
          }
          return of(count)
        }),
      )
    }).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: The condition can be different by always based on value rather than a counter. The multiple of 5 was just an example.

Comment: Ya you can define any local variables inside defer operator to control ur logic

Answer (score 1):

Your example is actually remarkably close to the working solution, no need for new custom operators.

See the section on "Buffering" here:

https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd

And the working example here:

https://thinkrx.io/gist/cef1572743cbf3f46105ec2ba56228cd

It uses the same approach you already have, with `bufferToggle` and `windowToggle`, it looks like the main difference is you need to `share` your pause/active subject-

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants a stream that pauses based on a value in the stream satisfying a given condition. This value could also come from the buffer so the whole buffer isn't released on every unpause.